# disply text on bar when hovering bar, in broken_barh

Tags: python-3.x, hover

I’m trying to build `broken_barh` plot, where wean I’m hovering over `bar(h)` I would like some text (any string) to show on the bar.
Any idea?

Comment: Hi, Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you use this example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_barh.html. can you make the text upper when I'm hovering each bar?